# Установка готового сайта на Yii2 basic на хостинг www.000webhost.com

Tags: yii2, хостинг, composer

Мне прислали зипованный сайт на Yii2 вместе с *.sql - базой данных. Я завёл себе аккаунт на www.000webhost.com (Hostinger.com). Пока он бесплатный. Там не такие уж крутые возможности. Через ftp перекачал сайт. Из папки web перекачал всё в корневую папку сайта public_html , переделал .htaccess под неё. А всё остальное перекачал возле папки public_html. Тестовая индексная страница с var_dump('YES') заработала. При попытке запустить полноценное приложение выходит следующая ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Swift' not found in /storage/ssd2/350/5238350/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php:30 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd2/350/5238350/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): require() #1 /storage/ssd2/350/5238350/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(56): composerRequire41c6c3c847bc23c7815d9ececd111f77('2c102faa651ef8e...', '/storage/ssd2/3...') #2 /storage/ssd2/350/5238350/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit41c6c3c847bc23c7815d9ececd111f77::getLoader() #3 /storage/ssd2/350/5238350/public_html/index.php(20): require('/storage/ssd2/3...') #4 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd2/350/5238350/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php on line 30

У меня 2 вопроса:
1) В соединении с базой данных, которую я создал нужно указывать

```
host=https://databases.000webhost.com;
```

Вот как здесь:

```
return [
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
//'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=text',
//'username' => 'root',
//'password' => '123qwe',
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=https://databases.000webhost.com; dbname=base_name',
'username' => 'login', 
'password' => 'password',
'charset' => 'utf8',
```

];

или указывать

```
host=localhost
```

2) Если я включу ПРЕМИУМ аккаунт, то я смогу связываться по ssh с сервером сайта через putty. Смогу ли я установить там composer и обновить его для данного сайта? И если я это сделаю, то всё заработает? Ведь ошибка выходит от необновлённости composer'а. Как мне поступить?

Answer (score 1):

Доброе утро.

1) При регистрации аккаунта на хостинге Вам должны были дать доступы к БД, ftp и панели управления. Вот Вы и посмотрите, какие доступы должны быть к БД, какой именно host надо указывать.

2) Возможно. Задайте этот вопрос поддержке хостинга.

Так же проверьте, какую версию php используют на хостинге. Возможно, что версия ниже, чем требуется для yii2.

p.s. Не надо указывать личные данные(логин, пароль к БД) в вопросе)))

p.s.s

> Из папки web перекачал всё в корневую папку сайта public_html , переделал .htaccess под неё.

А Вы поменяли пути в файле index.php, который находится в web? В нём как раз прописано куда обращаться, к каким директориям и к каким файлам.
Возможно надо изменить следующим образом.

```
// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../public_html/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
  require(__DIR__ . '/../public_html/config/web.php'),
  require (__DIR__ . '/../public_html/config/web-local.php'),
  require (__DIR__ . '/../public_html/config/common.php'),
  require (__DIR__ . '/../public_html/config/common-local.php')
);

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Или, вместо public_html укажите директорию проекта.

.htaccess в этом случае не нужен.

На название файлов не обращайте внимание, у Вас они могут называться по-другому

Comment: Спасибо. Я вопрос поправил. Версия php 7.1 - Вполне достаточная для Yii2. Там есть возможность выбрать версию php. Может быть лучше поставить ту версию, под которую разрабатывался сайт? Да, но всё таки ошибка связана с папкой vendor. Этот сайт был готовый, но когда я его перебросил на Hostinger (www.000webhost.com), то он выдал вот такую ошибку. Ведь composer-то надо обновлять?

Comment: Я все эти доступы знаю. Они есть (ftp,БД). А вот какой хост указывать для БД - там как-то двояко указано. То ли localhost, то ли https://databases.000webhost.com . Там в инфе о БД указано, что хост: localhost. Я это поправил. Но ошибка вся та же.

Comment: Я просто переформулирую вопрос: обновление composer'а и очистка его кэша что-нибудь даст? Типа composer update и composer clearcache

Comment: Дополнил ответ.